# Ntp service don't runs and timedate are wrong

Tags: ntp

My raspberry was wrong time and date. I run 'ps auxwww | grep ntp' and i get:

`pi        7282  0.0  0.1   4248  1480 pts/0    S+   05:50   0:00 grep --color=auto ntp`

So i don't have ntp service running..

`sudo systemctl status ntp.service`

```
 ● ntp.service - LSB: Start NTP daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ntp)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-03-03 05:42:47 WET; 9min ago
  Process: 5126 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ntp start (code=exited, status=2)

Mar 03 05:42:47 raspberrypi ntp[5126]: /etc/init.d/ntp: 6: /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks: Syntax er...pected
Mar 03 05:42:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ntp.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
Mar 03 05:42:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start NTP daemon.
Mar 03 05:42:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit ntp.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full
```

If i trỹ install again ntp, gives so many errors:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ntp is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_TIME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_MONETARY = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_CTYPE = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_ADDRESS = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_TELEPHONE = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_NAME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_MEASUREMENT = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_IDENTIFICATION = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_NUMERIC = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_PAPER = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up ntp (1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-7+deb8u2) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported;  falling back to defaults
Job for ntp.service failed. See 'systemctl status ntp.service' and   'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ntp, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package ntp (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
ntp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I read many similar problems but none helped me ..

I tried solve the locale problem, but gives me identical error:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_PAPER = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_ADDRESS = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_MONETARY = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_NUMERIC = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_TELEPHONE = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_IDENTIFICATION = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_MEASUREMENT = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_CTYPE = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_TIME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_NAME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
 Generating locales (this might take a while)...
 en_GB.UTF-8... done
 Generation complete.
 perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
 perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_TIME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_MONETARY = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_CTYPE = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_ADDRESS = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_TELEPHONE = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_NAME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_MEASUREMENT = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_IDENTIFICATION = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_NUMERIC = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_PAPER = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LANG = "C"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_TIME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_MONETARY = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_CTYPE = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_ADDRESS = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_TELEPHONE = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_NAME = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_MEASUREMENT = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_IDENTIFICATION = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_NUMERIC = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LC_PAPER = "pt_PT.UTF-8",
LANG = "C"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

How can i update Raspberry Time/Date automatically?

Comment: Solve the locale issue first.  Reinstalling software because of an error you do not understand is a [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_science) activity.  By analogy, if I have a toaster that fails to make toast because it is not plugged in, but I do not understand toasters and so assume it is broken, buying a new toaster will not fix the problem and only result in me wasting time and money.

Comment: Also I think the OP needs to check if he/she is actually connected to the Internet. If the ntp server does not respond, I don't assume the date will be updated.

Comment: I tried solve the locale problem. I run sudo locale-gen pt_PT pt_PT.UTF-8
and sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales but the last one gives me the same error..

Comment: @R.Rodrigues what about `sudo /etc/init.d/ntp restart` and then `date` does it give you something? Also are you `ssh`'ing into your Pi?

Comment: Yes i'm acessing with ssh...

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/ntp restart
/etc/init.d/ntp: 6: /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks: Syntax error: "}" unexpected

Comment: Ok I will give an answer your question with some perspective in mind of your situation.

Comment: Have you disabled systemd-timesyncd? If you don't do that ntpd won't run because systemd will kill it (to allow systemd-timesyncd to run).

Answer (score 2):

### Locale Issue

Since you are accessing your Pi over`ssh`, I think the following methods might help you solve the `locale` errors.

- Stop  forwarding your machine's locale to the Raspberry Pi. Simple comment out the following line in your machines `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

  ```
  # SendEnv LANG LC_*
  ```

  This will stop sending your Portuguese locale to your raspberry pi.
- You can try generating Portuguese `locale` on the Pi: `sudo locale-gen pt`
- You can set explicitly English to your Pi by writing into `~/.bashrc` (try `LANGUAGE = "pt"` for Portuguese):

  ```
  export LANGUAGE="en"
  export LANG="C"
  export LC_MESSAGES="C"
  ```

### NTP Issues

I am not sure if your Pi is connected to public internet, if so you can just ping Google:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
```

If the ping is not reachable that means you are not connected to the public Internet.

If your internal network has a properly configured NTP. try resetting using :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop
sudo ntpd -qg
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start
```

and then try `date`. I think this should get your work done.

#### Sources

[AskUbuntuSE Thread for `setting locale failed`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144235/locale-variables-have-no-effect-in-remote-shell-perl-warning-setting-locale-f)

Comment: I get this error, when tried stop ntp:  sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop
/etc/init.d/ntp: 6: /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks: Syntax error: "}" unexpected

Comment: try `sudo systemctl stop ntp.service` and perform the `/etc/init.d/` again? see if that helps?

Comment: No, it's the same thing

Comment: The service was already stopped .., when i tried stop again, gives me the same error

Comment: okay. maybe one last try. `sudo apt-get remove --purge ntp` and finally `sudo apt-get install ntp`.

Comment: Error again when i make install... `dpkg: error processing package ntp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ntp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48402/dpkg-new-pre-installation-script-returned-error-exit-status-1#48471

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was because the ntp process didnt have permissions to start

have ubuntu 20.04

This fixed the problem:
sudo chmod 755 /usr/sbin/ntpd

Comment: After I could start the ntp deamon with sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start and the time was updated.

Comment: How did you change permissions in /usr/sbin in the first place?